# How to handle base class updates with mongo jpa in a Springboot app?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, repository

how can I properly handle an update of the base class when using inheritance for mongo entities?

Base class:

```
@Document
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @UniqueElements
    protected String uid;

    protected String photoUrl;
    protected Address homeAddress;

    protected Gender gender;
    protected List<Kid> kids;
    protected GeneralInfo generalInfo;


    protected List<Address> addresses;


    protected String instanceId;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(User user) {
        this.uid = user.getUid();
        this.photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
        this.homeAddress = user.getHomeAddress();
        this.gender = user.getGender();
        this.kids = user.getKids();
        this.generalInfo = user.getGeneralInfo();
        this.addresses = user.getAddresses();
        this.instanceId = user.getInstanceId();
    }
}
```

Children:

```
@Document
public class Sitter extends User{

    private int childCareExperienceYrs;
    private AgeRange preferredKidsAgeRange;
    private List<Skill> skills;
    private String talents;
    private LivingSpace livingSpace;
    @JsonProperty
    private boolean pets;
    @JsonProperty
    private boolean hasCar;
    @JsonProperty(value = "available")
    private boolean available;
}


@Document
public class Parent extends User{

}
```

The properties inherited from User are saved in the children documents.
When I update a User property the child tables are not updated.

For example, when changing the user address, the 'Sitter' document will still have the old address.

How to make any change from the base class to reflect on child classes too?

Does this situation require an update query for each child when the base class is changed?